# Find all strongly connected elements

Tags: python, numpy, graph

I have a list which looks like that:

```
elements=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(3,5),(5,6),(12,13)]
```

I want to have all elenents which are strongly connected to be listed.

For the given list, elements would be: `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]`

Please suggest how I can do that

Comment: Can you use `networkx` or similar, or is this a homework problem that you need to do barebones?

Comment: Can you please suggest how I can use networkx for undirected graph? cause in that case I can not use nx.strongly_connected_components(G)

Comment: These elements seem to be connected, but not strongly connected if my memory is correct.  And by your definition of connected, shouldn't 12 and 13 be grouped?

Comment: You can use `networkx` for both directed and undirected graphs. But your latest comment doesn't make sense, "strongly connected" is a term only for *directed graphs*. If the graph was not directed, then [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] would all be in the same component.

Comment: Just to add to @user3483203 — to be *strongly* connected each element should be reachable from the others. But if you are at `3`, you can't get to `1` or `2` assuming this is a directed graph. I recommend drawing this out with nodes and arrows.

Comment: Thanks, I mean that I need to search for groups of elements which are interconnected ,where from each element i can reach other elements of the group ( sorry if I am wrong, but this what I called "strongly connected". So basicly I need to find such groups from a given list

Comment: @AlexCh for undirected graphs the term is just connected, not strongly connected, and your graph has two groups of connected components, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `[12, 13]`.  In your example, it seems like you think `3` is a different case because it connects `1` and `2` to `4` and `5`, but that's not the case.

Comment: But is there any way to detect groups from that list where all elements are bounded like 1,2 3 and 3,4,5. By bounded I mean that 1 connected with 2 and 3, 2 with 1,3 and 3 with 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Kosaraju's algorithm to find strongly connected components in any graph.
I think you may find it on geeksforgeeks website. It goes something like this.

Let's say there are 5 nodes, 0 through 4.
0,1,2 are strongly connected, 3 and 4 are strongly connected. 3 connects to say 0.

Then the algorithm goes : (source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/)

1) Create an empty stack ‘S’ and do DFS traversal of a graph. In DFS traversal, after calling recursive DFS for adjacent vertices of a vertex, push the vertex to stack. In the above graph, if we start DFS from vertex 0, we get vertices in stack as 1, 2, 4, 3, 0.

2) Reverse directions of all arcs to obtain the transpose graph.

3) One by one pop a vertex from S while S is not empty. Let the popped vertex be ‘v’. Take v as source and do DFS (call DFSUtil(v)). The DFS starting from v prints strongly connected component of v. In the above example, we process vertices in order 0, 3, 4, 2, 1 (One by one popped from stack).

Edit : SCC for undirected graphs doesn't make sense. Theoretically SCCs are defined for directed graphs alone.

Comment: Kosaraju's is exclusively for directed graphs.  If you ran it on his graph treating it as a directed graph, none of his nodes would be strongly connected, so this wouldn't accomplish his desired grouping.  Also copy pasting from an external site isn't a particularly useful answer.

Comment: @user3483203 to your last point, I disagree---if the external resource answers the question, it's OK to link it (e.g. documentation), and the answerer *should* include the text in case the link disappears.

Comment: @alkasm completely agree about documentation, but this is just plagiarizing a tutorial website.